# python, i am trying to replace all all examples of a regex phrase in a column, but got stuck

Tags: python, pandas

So the head of the frame looks like below.

I want to strip out that < *chars* > < *chars* > etc.

```
Name    Damage  Velocity    Mana    Use Time    Knockback   Sell
NaN Icicle Staff    12  11  6   29 (Average)    2 (Very Weak)   <span data-info="0"> <span data-info="0"> <spa...
NaN Plasma Rod  8   6   10  35 (Slow)   2.5 (Very Weak) <span data-info="0"> <span data-info="0"> <spa...
NaN Sky Glaze   15  15  8   24 (Fast)   3.50 (Weak) <span data-info="0"> <span data-info="0"> <spa...
NaN Wulfrum Staff   10  9   4   19 (Very Fast)  3 (Very Weak)   <span data-info="0"> <span data-info="0"> <spa...
NaN Aquamarine Staff    10  9   3   14 (Very Fast)  2.5 (Very Weak) <span data-info="0"> <span data-info="0"> <spa...
```

I tried to use

```
wand_frame = wand_frame.replace('(<.+>)','')
```

and

```
wand_frame=wand_frame.replace('(\<.+\>)','')
```

but it does nothing. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

replace is for string and didn't recognize REGEX syntax, prefer use re.sub :

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

in your case :

```
wand_frame = re.sub('(<.+>)','', wand_frame)
```

Comment: After further investigation, I have found that i need to extract the number, not just clear out a regex. Your help is appreciated nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear char between `<>` you can use reg like code below , also want number you what to extract as mentioned in comment .

```
  import   re

  wand_frame  = 'NaN Icicle Staff    12  11  6   29 (Average)    2 (Very Weak)   <span 
  data-info="0"> <span data-info="0">\n' \
  'NaN Plasma Rod  8   6   10  35 (Slow)   2.5 (Very Weak) <span data-info="0"> <span 
   data-info="0">\n' \
  'NaN Plasma Rod  8   6   10  35 (Slow)   2.5 (Very Weak) <span data-info="0"> <span 
  data-info="0">'

  wand_frame  =    re.sub('<[a-zA-Z0-9\"\=\-\s\'\@\_\?\*\&\%\$]*>','',wand_frame)

  print (wand_frame)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 NaN Icicle Staff    12  11  6   29 (Average)    2 (Very Weak)    
 NaN Plasma Rod  8   6   10  35 (Slow)   2.5 (Very Weak)  
 NaN Plasma Rod  8   6   10  35 (Slow)   2.5 (Very Weak)
```